# How to turn shape in jpg image into coordinates. Explained please. Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, image, opencv

I am trying to input the image, L shaped image in black:

[image: L shaped image in black]

into my Python code and receive back the coordinates of each corner. I get confused with the pixel approach of cv2 and am trying to figure out a way to create two arrays, x and y, of the corners. Examples for this shape could return:

```
x = [1, 3, 3, 9, 9, 2, 2, 1]
y = [1, 1, 9, 9, 11, 11, 10, 10]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's not clear, at least for me, what are you trying to accomplish. Do you want to use or not the cv2 approach?

Comment: @HemersonTacon I am open using the cv2 approach, but I am a little unfamiliar with it and unsure how to turn the complex coordinates of the pixels into simple coordinates as shown in my question.

Answer (score 2):

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6e6NbNegChU) to achieve a corner detection:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = np.float32(gray)

corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(gray, 100, 0.01, 10)
corners = np.int0(corners)

for corner in corners:
    x,y = corner.ravel()
    #x and y are your values of the lsit
    cv2.circle(img,(x,y),3,255,-1)
   
cv2.imshow('Corner',img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

This result looks like this:
The Blue dots are the corners.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and try to improve your answer.

Comment: edited the answer. Sorry for bad answer hope this is better!

Comment: @SirBaum Thank you so much for the helpful link! I achieved the same result. But I am more looking to make two arrays, one of x and one y, for the corners. I am having trouble converting the corner pixel coords into useful coordinates for my program. For example, I am getting [[[570 781]]

 [[326 537]]

 [[977 537]]

 [[977 374]]

 [[326 374]]

 [[733 781]]

 [[733 130]]

 [[570 130]]

 [[568 539]]

 [[735 539]]

 [[735 372]]

 [[568 372]]] ....

Comment: Aren't that the pixel values? Your Image has an resolution of 1260x945, that could be the "coordinates" of the corners

Comment: @SirBaum You are right, the ravel() function doesnt seem to store the coordinates for me too well, so I am going to try to append through the for loop to get my arrays. Thank you!